# Return RACSignal method in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, racsignal

I have the following method in Obj-C:

```
- (RACSignal *)fetchCurrentConditionsForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%f&lon=%f&units=metric", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    return [[self fetchJSONFromURL:url] map:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        return [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[WXCondition class] fromJSONDictionary:json error:nil];
    }];
}
```

My conversion to Swift:

```
func fetchJSONFromURL(url: NSURL) -> RACSignal {

}

func fetchCurrentConditionsForLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> RACSignal {
    let urlString = NSString(format: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%f&lon=%f&units=metric", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)
    let url = NSURL.URLWithString(urlString)

    // Convert to Swift?        
    return [[self fetchJSONFromURL:url] map:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        return [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[WXCondition class] fromJSONDictionary:json error:nil];
    }];
}
```

Having trouble with this map in Swift:

```
return [[self fetchJSONFromURL:url] map:^(NSDictionary *json) {
    return [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[WXCondition class] fromJSONDictionary:json error:nil];
}];
```

Everything is compiling properly, but is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you have `import CoreLocation` at the top of your Swift code?

Comment: @dpassage: Yes, I just included it to get ride of the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` error. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried in a project, but perhaps this wil do

```
return fetchJSONFromURL(url).map { (json: NSDictionary) in
    return MTLJSONAdapter.modelOfClass(WXCondition.self, fromJSONDictionary: json, error: nil)
} as RACSignal
```

Comment: This isn't working as `map` is not a member of `NSDictionary`. My code is working, I'm just not sure whether it's the right way to go about it.

Comment: then how is the Objective-C code working? Who's adding `map` to `NSDictionary`?

Comment: I think it's a special `RACSignal` return map.

Comment: Does `fetchJSONFromURL` return a `NSDictionary` in Objective-C?

Comment: No, it returns `RACSignal`.

Comment: @gotnull then why in swift your method is returning `NSDictionary`?

Comment: Oh crap! I made a mistake in my question :(

Comment: So now it should have `map` method and my code should compile, right?

Comment: have you tried it? Where does the `block` parameter name come from? Blocks are replaced by closures in swift.

Comment: Nope, error: `AnyObject!` is not a subtype of `RacSignal`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55582/discussion-between-gotnull-and-gabriele-petronella).

Comment: @gotnull ok, that's because in Objective-C it returns `id`. Try casting it to `RACSignal` as I do in my updated answer