# Converting Objective-C Block into Closure the Swift way

Tags: objective-c, closures, objective-c-blocks, swift, reactive-cocoa

I have successfully converted the following method from *Obj-C* to *Swift*:

After learning how [blocks are replaced by closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208133/return-racsignal-method-in-swift/24208629?noredirect=1#comment37379212_24208629) in *Swift*.

**Obj-C:**

```
- (RACSignal *)fetchCurrentConditionsForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%f&lon=%f&units=imperial", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    return [[self fetchJSONFromURL:url] map:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        return [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[WXCondition class] fromJSONDictionary:json error:nil];
    }];
}
```

**Swift:**

```
func fetchCurrentConditionsForLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> RACSignal {
    let urlString = NSString(format: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%f&lon=%f&units=metric", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)
    let url = NSURL.URLWithString(urlString)

    return fetchJSONFromURL(url).map { json in
        return MTLJSONAdapter.modelOfClass(WXCondition.self, fromJSONDictionary: json as NSDictionary, error: nil)
    }
}
```

However, I'm having trouble converting the following return map block to *Swift*:

[image]

```
func fetchHourlyForecastForLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> RACSignal {
    var urlString = NSString(format: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=%f&lon=%f&units=metric&cnt=12", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)
    let url = NSURL.URLWithString(urlString)

    /* Original Obj-C:

    return [[self fetchJSONFromURL:url] map:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        RACSequence *list = [json[@"list"] rac_sequence];
            return [[list map:^(NSDictionary *item) {
                return [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[WXCondition class] fromJSONDictionary:item error:nil];
            }] array];
        }];
    }
     */

    // My attempt at conversion to Swift
    // (I can't resolve `rac_sequence` properly). Kind of confused
    // as to how to cast it properly and return
    // it as an "rac_sequence" array.

    return fetchJSONFromURL(url).map { json in
        let list = RACSequence()
        list = [json["list"] rac_sequence]
        return (list).map { item in {
            return MTLJSONAdapter.modelOfClass(WXCondition.self, fromJSONDictionary: item as NSDictionary, error: nil)
        } as NSArray
    }
}
```

If it helps, this is what `rac_sequence` is:

```
- (RACSequence *)rac_sequence {
    return [RACArraySequence sequenceWithArray:self offset:0];
}
```

`RACArraySequence()`:

```
+ (instancetype)sequenceWithArray:(NSArray *)array offset:(NSUInteger)offset;
```

**EDIT:** The fetch method returns a [RACSignal](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal.h) not an `NSArray`:

```
func fetchJSONFromURL(url: NSURL) -> RACSignal {

}
```

Comment: What a well formatted question! One quick comment is to always use initializer syntax. `NSURL(string:urlString)` instead of `NSURL.urlWithString`. You used it for `NSString` but not `NSURL` :p

Comment: @JackWu: Thanks for the suggestions! Appreciate it! Any particular reason why it's better to use initializer syntax?

Comment: Well in Swift that is the only way to do initialization. No more class initializers vs instance initializers. ObjC initializers and factory methods both get translated into this new syntax automatically. Its the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you simply forgot the return type in the function declaration. The declaration should look something like this:

```
func fetchHourlyForecastForLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> RACSignal { //...rest of function
```

Because the return type is now named you can then remove the `as NSArray` cast in your return statement at the end of the function. Hope this helps!

Comment: I've updated what `fetchJSONFromURL()` returns. It's actually not an `NSArray` it's a `RACSignal`.

Comment: Yeah, although there's still a lot of code that doesn't compile. That's not the only change that's needed to port that function over.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention: if you have a collection you have to put angle brackets and say what it will contain (e.g `Array<Int>` for a list of integers).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
func fetchHourlyForecastForLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,completion:(AnyObject) -> Void)  {

   //after getting the NSArray (maping)
   completion(_array)
}
```